# Possible to define Macro with minor difference in output

Tags: rust, macros

I would like to use a macro in a number of places in my code, but half of them require a version of the macro which returns `Foo` whilst the other places require `Ok(Foo)` only on a certain code path in the macro - returning isn't guaranteed.

The basic structure of the macro is:

```rust
macro_rules! long_macro {
    ( $self:ident ) => {
 
        ...  // lots of code goes here
 
        if $self.foo() {
            return Foo  // or Ok(Foo)
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The macro is *very large* so I'd like to avoid defining two separate macros when they're 99% the same, just this difference in return value on one code path.

Is there any way to use a single macro to neatly accommodate both call site types? I can't simply wrap the macro invocation in `Ok(long_macro!(self))` at some call sites because it only returns under one code path.

Comment: What stops you from doing the same thing you would do if those were functions and not macros? Extract common code and put it in helper macro.

Comment: Why can't you pass the return value (`Foo` or `Ok(Foo)`) to the macro?

Comment: What do you think about passing into the macro an additional `$W:ident` (return wrapper) and then on the lines which return in the definition `$W(...)`? I can then invoke either `long_macro!(..., Ok)` or `long_macro!(..., identity)` <-- from `std::convert::identity`.

Comment: To answer why I don't pass `Foo` or `Ok(Foo)` to the macro, in reality `Foo` is actually a 6 line formatted function call, it would require its own function (shorthand for taking these particular args) which I'd prefer to avoid to justify this macro.